# What are the best set of tools to develop cross-platform phone apps/games

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone

I want to develop a card game to deploy on multiple platforms: Android, iOS, Windows 8 and Windows Phone 7.5/8.

After a web search I found out PhoneGap, but unfortunately my background is C#, and my knowledge of HTML5 Canvas is almost Zero.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Use `uinty3D`or a open source `LIBGDX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Monotouch
2. Corona
3. PhoneGap
4. Titanium
5. sencha touch

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely choose MonoGame which is a replication of the XNA game platform on the Mono framework. I believe it's currently the best way to reuse most of your code across multiple platforms while still developing native apps and not HTML apps backed by a framework like PhoneGap.

John Sonmez talks a lot about it:
http://simpleprogrammer.com/2012/08/05/introduction-to-monogame/

You can also get a lot of your questions answered hearing the below podcasts from **[The Tablet Show](http://www.thetabletshow.com)**:
http://thetabletshow.com/?ShowNum=49
http://thetabletshow.com/?ShowNum=60

Also check [MvvmCross](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross) framework, which can give you some hints on how to get most of your code reused across platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't knew MonoGame

Answer (score 0):

I would say MonoTouch+MonoDroid+MonoGame (XNA) which will give you cross compatibility (with slight adjustments on every platform required..) with iOS, Android, WP7, WP8 as well as Windows/OSX and Linux.